# Inkscape - Create a a path with normals perpendicular to another path

Tags: inkscape, path-effects

In Inkscape, is it possible to draw a path as illustrated in the figure below? The normal of the *New path* is always perpendicular to the normal of the *Original path*. Although there are some path tools in Inscape, e.g. Inset, Offset, and Dynamic Offset, they only seem to work on closed paths.

[image]

The code for the **Original path** is listed below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<svg width="210mm" height="297mm" viewBox="0 0 210 297" version="1.1" id="svg690" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <g id="layer1">
    <path style="fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:2px" d="M 80.082 111.953 C 80.082 111.953 89.336 105.862 89.561 111.091 C 89.787 116.32 80.752 123.906 81.02 128.279 C 81.288 132.652 90.234 126.964 90.234 126.964"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While the offset operations in the 'Path' menu only work with closed shapes, there is also the somewhat newer 'Offset' path-effect that *does* work with open paths. On top of that, it gives you much greater control over the result.

Open the 'Path → Path Effects...' panel, add a new effect and look for 'Offset'. Now you can drag the new handle while in node editing mode, similar to the 'Dynamic Offset' menu-item, or set the exact value in the parameters.

[image: Offset path-effect example]

Comment: This is just GREAT! Thanks